# Ada: Declaration & assignment overhead

Tags: initialization, ada, elaboration

I'm curious about the initialization within Ada procedures:
Suppose I have the following procedure:

```
procedure Foo (Bar : Integer) is
    Another_Bar : Integer := Bar;
begin
    ...
end Foo;
```

Should the assignment to `Another_Bar` have the same overhead as

```
procedure Foo2 (Bar : Integer) is
    Another_Bar : Integer;
begin
    Another_Bar := Bar;
    ...
end Foo;
```

My question is essentially if both assignments generate the same assembly instructions and thus are equal in speed? (without detailing the target machine)

Comment: That’s going to depend on the optimisation level, the target architecture, the compiler release, what `Another_Bar` is used for, etc ... so, who knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the Ada language standard, there is no general reason why those two forms of code should have different performance. It would all depend on the target machine and the compiler being used. Depending on the rest of the code in the procedure, some compilers could even completely optimize away the `Another_Bar` variable.

However, there is a semantic difference, which could be important if the subtypes of `Bar` and `Another_Bar` were different -- for example, if `Another_Bar` were declared as `Positive` instead of `Integer`. Namely, in the first form any exception raised by the initialization of `Another_Bar` (say, because `Bar` has a negative value) is not handled by the possible exception handlers in the procedure itself, but is propagated to the caller. In the second form, where `Another_Bar` is assigned after the `begin`, exceptions from that assignment can be handled by the procedure's own exception handlers.

Comment: This is interesting, given the elaboration (of declared variables) and code execution are described as separate processes in the Ada documentations.